# How to get specific item in list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following generic list.  How do I pull a single, specific item from this list?

```
<ul>
  <li id="t1">topic 1</li>
  <li id="t2">topic 2</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$li = $( "li" ).get(1);
console.log (($li).value());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5p86Lbpz/1/

Error:

> 0 is not a function

I'm following the pattern from here: https://api.jquery.com/get/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. When you do `get()`, a native javascript DOM element is returned
2. When `value` is applicable, it is a **property**, not a *function*
3. For `li` elements, there is no `value` property, rather `textContent`

```js
$li = $("li").get(1);
console.log($li.textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="t1">topic 1</li>
  <li id="t2">topic 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use `eq()`, which is better than `get()` in my opinion because it returns the element as jQuery object so you can use jQuery functions on it like `text()` for example.

```
$("li").eq(1).text();
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about the accepted answer.  Nice

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
jQuery("li:first").html(); //This will return "topic 1"
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for posting it.